# With Symfony, can I check how many db connections open and close on a page load?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I've started a new(ish) job and inherited a codebase that was heavily model-based involving lots of database calls. An example page could have, say, 50 users on it and the following db connections would happen for every single user:

`$user->getName`
`$user->getDob`
`$user->getDepartment`
etc etc

Rather than one SQL query getting all this information, it's making multiple calls for every entity on the page. I'm keen to get an understanding of the problem pages on the system by looking at pages that do a lot of db calls. Is there a design pattern I can follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The [Symfony Profiler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html) should help you check what's going on during a page load.